# Failing to register custom subclasses of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two custom subclasses of UITableViewCell that Xcode doesn't like. I'm trying to call the registerClass:forReuseIdentifier: method like so:

```
static NSString* gameCellIdentifier = @"GameCell";
static NSString* buttonCellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";
// Register the classes for use.
[self.tableView registerClass:ButtonCell forCellReuseIdentifier:buttonCellIdentifier];
[self.tableView registerClass:GameCell forCellReuseIdentifier:gameCellIdentifier];
```

And I'm getting the error, "Unexpected interface name ... expected expression instead." error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send a `Class` to `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` so you need to do this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[ButtonCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:buttonCellIdentifier];
[self.tableView registerClass:[GameCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:gameCellIdentifier];
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. I just needed to do [ButtonCell class] instead.